# How can $\frac1s(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}-1) = \frac1s(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, summation, taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble with a proof of the moment generating function via Taylor series in [Introduction to probability, statistics and random processes](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_1_3_moment_functions.php) which, in relevant part, states the following:
$$\frac1s(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}-1) = \frac1s(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!})$$

I think I am overlooking something elementary because I get the following.

$$\frac1s(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}-1) = \frac1s(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}-1) + \frac1s(\frac{s^0}{0!}-1) = \frac1s(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}-1) = \frac1s(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!})- \frac{k}{s} $$

is this because in the limit as $k ->\infty, \frac{s^k}{k!}>>\frac{k}{s}$ so the latter term is dropped or am I missing something more basic? Any point in the right direction would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: $\frac{s^0}{0!}=1$

Comment: The $1$ doesn't get distributed. $(\sum X -1)=(\sum X) -1 $

Comment: In your succession of equalities, the RHS depends on $k$ whereas the LHS does not. This does not make a lot of sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{s^k}{k!}=1+\dfrac{s}{1!}+\dfrac{s^2}{2!}+\dfrac{s^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{s^k}{k!}=\dfrac{s}{1!}+\dfrac{s^2}{2!}+\dfrac{s^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{s^k}{k!}-1=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{s^k}{k!}$$
Dividing by $s$, you get the desired result.

Hope this helps. Ask anything it you not clear :)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain this! I misunderstood $(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!}-1)$ to mean $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{s^k}{k!}-1)$ so I had $\frac{s}{1!}-\frac{1}{s}+\frac{s^2}{2!}-\frac{1}{s}$. In general can we always assume that $\sum$ only applies to the term immediately following it unless there is a parenthesis after the summation $\sum()$?

Comment: @phntm: It depends honestly. Oftentimes, it is clear from the context. Using brackets is always better.